# Nice (I think!) probability problems

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

These two problems are not really difficult, but I find them very pleasant and with somewhat surprising answers being so similarly stated.

*Long* game: At each stage I try to guess the number you're thinking of, and we'll play until I *succeed*. In the first stage you choose a number in $\{1,2\}$; in the second one, a number in $\{1,2,3\}$; and so on: at every stage the range increases by one. Let $X$ be the needed number of stages. What is the probability of $X$ being an *odd* number?

*Short* game: At each stage I try to guess the number you're thinking of, and we'll play until I *fail*. In the first stage you choose a number in $\{1,2\}$; in the second one, a number in $\{1,2,3\}$; and so on: at every stage the range increases by one. Let $X$ be the needed number of stages. What is the probability of $X$ being an *even* number?

I would also appreciate any previous reference of these facts and of similar questions in textbooks or websites.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Hint: To compute the probability that the long game ends on step $~k,~$ you multiply the probability that the first $~(k-1)~$ steps failed by the probability that step $~k~$ itself succeeded.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I know the answers and how to solve them (they are not really difficult, I know), but I have never seen them elsewhere and considered it a good idea to present them here.

Comment: So, your intent is (in effect) to present a *self-answer* question, which is perfectly fine on MathSE.  In that event, simply put a line at the start of your question indicating that this is a  self-answer question.  Then, answer your own question, in an answer box.  As it stands now, given the MathSE protocol article that I cited, your posting is (for the moment) low quality.

Comment: OK, I'm editing my question to make it clear that I know the answers, but I'd rather not provide any solution yet... I feel the post would be much less interesting for most of readers if I provide the answer instead of finding it by themselves...

Comment: This is not a good idea.  Much better to trust the reader to try the problem on their own, if they wish.  MathSE is not normally used as a problem-challenge forum, but is instead primarily intended for someone who needs Math help.  Not showing work at the time of the posting is **really** not a good idea at MathSE.

Comment: It might help to emphasize (literally, by italicizing) the difference between the two games ("succeed" vs "fail"). It took me a minute to hunt down that difference.

Comment: I guess you're right, @Brian Tung, thank you.

Comment: One thing you might consider is posting the answers, but hiding them behind "spoiler" formatting.   You do this by putting `>!` at the beginning of the line.  The text becomes invisible until the reader hovers over it.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s another approach with [probability generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function).

You’ve already given the probabilities for the two games: $P(X=k)=\frac1{k(k+1)}$ for the long game and $P(X=k)=\frac k{(k+1)!}$ for the short game. The corresponding probability generating functions are

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+1)}x^k
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1kx^k-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k+1}x^k
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^xt^{k-1}\mathrm dt-\frac1x\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^xt^k\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
\int_0^x\sum_{k=1}^\infty t^{k-1}\mathrm dt-\frac1x\int_0^x\sum_{k=1}^\infty t^k\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
\int_0^x\frac1{1-t}\mathrm dt-\frac1x\int_0^x\frac t{1-t}\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
-\log(1-x)-\frac{-x-\log(1-x)}x
\\
&=&
1+\log(1-x)\left(\frac1x-1\right)
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
g(x)
&=&
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac k{(k+1)!}x^k
\\
&=&
\frac1x\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^x\frac1{(k-1)!}t^k\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
\frac1x\int_0^x\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k-1)!}t^k\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
\frac1x\int_0^xt\mathrm e^t\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
\frac{\mathrm e^x(x-1)+1}x\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus the probability that the number of turns in the long game is odd is

$$
\frac{f(1)-f(-1)}2=\frac{1-(1-2\log2)}2=\log2
$$

(where $f(1)=1$ expresses the normalization of the distribution, so it doesn’t need to be worked out as a limit), and the probability that the number of turns in the short game is even is

$$
\frac{f(1)+g(-1)}2=\frac{1+(2\mathrm e^{-1}-1)}2=\mathrm e^{-1}\;.
$$

That was a bit more work than the direct approach, but now that we have the probability generating functions, we can answer lots of questions about these games quite easily. For instance, $f'(x)$ diverges at $x=1$, which shows that the long game deserves its name, as its expected length is infinite. The expected length of the short game, by contrast, is $g'(1)=\mathrm e-1$. The probability that the number of turns is a multiple of $4$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{f(1)+f(\mathrm i)+f(-1)+f(-\mathrm i)}4
&=&
\frac{1+1-2\log2+2\left(1-\frac\pi4-\frac{\log2}2\right)}4
\\
&=&
1-\frac34{\log2}-\frac\pi8
\\
&\approx&
9\%
\end{eqnarray}

for the long game and

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{g(1)+g(\mathrm i)+g(-1)+g(-\mathrm i)}4
&=&
\frac{1-\mathrm i+(1+i)\mathrm e^{\mathrm i}+2\mathrm e^{-1}-1+\mathrm i+(1-i)\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i}}4
\\
&=&
\frac{\mathrm e^{-1}+\cos1-\sin1}2
\\
&\approx&
3\%
\end{eqnarray}

for the short game.

[Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4666493.java) that checks these results by simulation.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Yes, I knew about the expectations, and anyway it is clear that the number of stages can be typically great in the first game but not in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

In the long game, the requested probability is $\log(2)$, where $\log$ is the natural logarithm: for any integer $k\ge 1$ the probability that $X=k$ is readily seen to be $\frac 1 {k(k+1)}$, and we have to compute
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{(2k+1)(2k+2)}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\big(\frac 1 {2k+1}-\frac 1 {2k+2}\big)\\[2pt]
&=\log(2):
\end{align*}
the partial sums up to $k=n$ are $H_{2n+1}-\frac 1 2\,(H_n + H_{n+1})$ (where $H_n=1+1/2+1/3+\dots + 1/n$), and their limit as $n\to\infty$ is $\log 2$ because of the well known fact that
$$
H_n=\log n +\gamma + o(n)\,.
$$

As for the short game, the probability in question is $1/e$: $X=k$ is very easily seen to have as probability $\frac{k}{(k+1)!}$ for any integer $k\ge 1$, so the answer is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k}{(2k+1)!} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k+1)-1}{(2k+1)!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{(2k)!} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{(2k+1)!}\\[2pt]
&=\sum_{n=2}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = e^{-1} = \frac 1 e
\end{align*}

Comment: Actually the partial sums for $k=0,1,\dots,n$ of the first series are the partial sums for $k=0,1,\dots 2n$ of the alternate series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}/k$